# Get clicked element's HTML using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am adding a class to the clicked element and getting the innerHTML of it, if the clicked element is a container. But if it is a HTML element and not a container, 
For eg., if the clicked element is an image `<img src="hello.png" />`(which is not a container and cannot use innerHTML), then i need to get the corresponding element tag, i.e. i need to get `<img src="hello.png" />`. So anyway to do this with pure JavaScript?

P.S. I don't want to use any JavaScript libraries here.

Comment: You want to go for pure HTML of the img tag, right?

Comment: @EnesUnal: Yes i need pure HTML of the img tag

Comment: Why not just get the `src` attribute and construct the image tag back? Of course `innerHMTL` is not gonna work there, there's no html inside an `img` tag...

Comment: blueiur's answer is right, BUT, if there is a lot of tags in parentNode of your tag, you will get a lot of tags' HTML code. If you construct the whole code, ADD a parent node to all your related HTMLs, there must be a way to do without this way, but I cannot think now.

Comment: May i know the reason for down vote, that is without any comment?

Comment: Do not blame the downvoters, go for your answer ;)

Comment: @elclanrs Can you please show how to do that? Because the element can be of any type and not only image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this...

```
<img src="hello.png" onclick="alert(outerHTML)" />
```

---

Note that `outerHTML` only recently gained Firefox support.

*This may look odd, but it does work.*

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/2GLjC/

If you use a different type of handler *(not inline)*, you could still use `outerHTML` from the context of the element.

---

A cross-browser solution to pick up more Firefox support could look like this...

```
function getOuterHTML(elem) {
    return elem.outerHTML || document.createElement("div")
                                     .appendChild(elem.cloneNode(true))
                                     .parentNode
                                     .innerHTML
}
```

So just pass your element to the `getOuterHTML` function, and it should return a correct result.

```
alert(getOuterHTML(this));
```

Comment: @EnesUnal: It's the weird scope chain of inline handlers. It includes the element itself as well as the `document` in the chain, so any properties on those elements can be accessed as variables.

Comment: I just want to know him if he use it from inline code. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: @amnotiam: Thanks for your great answer. But i also needs to support some older version of Firefox also... Any idea for that?

Comment: @Udhay: A typical solution is to clone the element, put the clone in a container, then get the `innerHTML` of the container. I'll update my answer with a function that'll work for both.